# How to know the IP address of the page visitor using Javascripts without using any external site/responder

Tags: javascript, networking, ip

I am developing a application in which I need to know the IP address of the person who hit the submit button of form (Javascript, jQuery etc are allowed) .

I have tried a lot of scripts that use the external hosts to do this but I can't use the same as there is masking of IP address used in the org.

This application is internal and hence I want a method to know the IP address in LAN as the request going out of the org gateway returns the gateway IP.

Kindly provide the support.

Comment: As far as I searched, the browser does not provide any API to access the IP (for security reasons I guess, or because of the possibility to have multiple IPs). The best I have is the [Node API](http://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_networkinterfaces), server side (sigh..). Maybe you could try to send an XHR and get your IP from there but it requires a server side anyway. :/ I hope someone comes with a better solution.

Comment: "_I want a method to know the IP address in LAN as the request going out of the org gateway returns the gateway IP._" That is only true in the case of NAPT, which is a kludge to extend the life of IPv4 until IPv6 becomes ubiquitous (IPv6 does not have NAT, and forbids NAPT), but then you must deal with things like Privacy Extensions, where it periodically and randomly changes the IP address. Also, there a businesses that own block of IPv4 addresses, and may have public IPv4 addresses assigned such that NAPT is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access local network information via the browser.

A user could have multiple network cards each having multiple IP addresses. The browser only knows if the user is online via `navigator.onLine`.

The only way to get the IP address of the user is to use a server within your organizations network. And depending on the network layout (LAN/WiFi) it could still be a problem.

Comment: thanks @osteenbergen. It has been a long time for this question but, I guess it is never too late to know. I have done this on my webserver to get the IP and then performed the further operation based on the same.